# Segmentation of sunspots

Tags: image-processing, code-review, astronomy, segmentation

I recently went for a walk with my camera and snapped a few pictures of the sun. The pictures didn't turn out too well, but this was to be expected without a telescope. I thought it might be a nice exercise to segment out the sunspots and see how my results compare to the data of [SOHO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_and_Heliospheric_Observatory). Here is what I came up with:

```
img = Import["http://i.imgur.com/4lDwE33.jpg"];
soho = Import["http://i.imgur.com/XNmroTf.jpg"];

(*determine center and radius of the sun in the the image*)
{center, radius} = 
  ComponentMeasurements[
    MorphologicalComponents[img, 0.2], {"Centroid", 
     "EquivalentDiskRadius"}][[1, 2]];

(*segment the sun from background, polar transformp, post process *)
ImageTransformation[img, 
  center + {Cos[#[[1]]], Sin[#[[1]]]}*#[[2]] &, {2 Pi radius, radius},
   DataRange -> Full, PlotRange -> {{0, 360 °}, {1, radius}}];
polar = ColorConvert[%, "LUV"];
mean = Mean@ImageData[polar][[All, All, 1]][[#]] & /@ 
   Range[Round[radius]];
normalPolar = 
  Image@Rescale[
    ImageData[polar][[All, All, 1]][[#]] - mean[[#]] & /@ 
     Range[Round[radius]]];

(*transform back to cartesien coordinates*)
normalCart = 
  ImageTransformation[
   normalPolar, {ArcTan @@ (radius - #), 
     Norm[# - radius]} &, {2 radius, 2 radius}, 
   DataRange -> {{-180 °, 180 °}, {0, radius}}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 2 radius}, {0, 2 radius}}];
(*segmentation of sun spots*)
segmentation = 
  ColorNegate@
   ImageAdd[
    Dilation[
     Binarize[ImageCorrelate[%, GaussianMatrix[6], CosineDistance], 
      0.253], 2.29], Graphics[Disk[center, radius]]];
(*generate spot labels*)
centroids = 
  ComponentMeasurements[
   SelectComponents[MorphologicalComponents[ColorNegate@segmentation],
     "Count", 10], {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "Label"}];
labeled = Show[normalCart,
   Graphics[{Red, Circle @@ # & /@ centroids[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]],
     MapThread[
      Text, {centroids[[All, 2, 3]] - 1, {0, 6 + #[[2]]} + #[[1]] & /@
         centroids[[All, 2, 1 ;; 2]]}]}]
   ];

(* plot:
"original image", "post processed image"
"segmented sun spots", "labeled post processed image"
"image from Solar and Heliospheric Observatory (SOHO)"
*)
GraphicsGrid[{{ImageCrop[img], normalCart}, {segmentation, 
   labeled}, {soho}}, Frame -> All, ImageSize -> 900]
```

[image]
[image]

While I'm quite happy with the result, I thought some of you guys might come up with some clever ideas to make the approach more robust and the results even better.

I'm also very thankful for a review of my code. You never stop learning!

Comment: Nice question. The part of the code that separates the sun from the background can be replaced by `ImageCrop@ImageMultiply[Binarize@img, img]` I think.

Comment: What is the problem with `MinDetect[img, .02]`?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well I decided to give it a bit of a go...First import the image and convert to grayscale, then crop to focus on the area of interest. Then I used a [`LaplacianGaussianFilter`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LaplacianGaussianFilter.html), which is often used in [blob detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blob_detection#The_Laplacian_of_Gaussian).

```
img = ImageAdjust@ColorConvert[Import["http://i.imgur.com/4lDwE33.jpg"], "Grayscale"];
smallimg = ImageAdjust@ImageTake[img, {200, 500}, {200, 600}];
logimg = ImageAdjust@LaplacianGaussianFilter[smallimg, {6,2}];

(* pretty colours! *)
coloredlogimg = Colorize[ColorNegate@logimg, ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors"];
GraphicsRow[{smallimg, coloredlogimg}, ImageSize -> Full]
```

[image]

The interesting thing about this is that it starts to reveal the separate sunspots right in the centre of the image, which are [distinct in the SOHO comparison image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AqEw.jpg) but less clear in your photo. This is what initially drew me to the question!

I then proceed to binarize the image (with an automatic threshold), do a distance transform followed by maxima detection, then finally use [`WatershedComponents`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WatershedComponents.html) to pick out the sunspots:

```
binimg = Binarize[logimg, Method -> "MinimumError"];
distimg = ImageAdjust@DistanceTransform@binimg;
maximg = MaxDetect[distimg, 0.2];
components = DeleteBorderComponents[
   WatershedComponents[logimg, maximg, Method -> "Rainfall"]];
measures = ComponentMeasurements[
   components, {"Centroid", "EquivalentDiskRadius", "Label"}];

g1 = Show[coloredlogimg, 
 Graphics[{Red,
   Map[Circle[#, 10] &, measures[[All, 2, 1]]], Blue, 
   MapThread[Text, {measures[[All, 2, 3]], 
     measures[[All, 2, 1]] + ConstantArray[{-5, 15}, Length@measures[[All, 2, 1]]]
      }]
    }]];
```

End result compared to the SOHO image? Pretty good! It's managed to separate out the central spot into two components (compared to the 3 evident in the SOHO image).

I did try to minimize the amount of user input needed to select appropriate parameters, but sadly it's affected by image noise. I also gave image deconvolution a try, but didn't get very far.

```
soho = ImageAdjust@Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/8AqEw.jpg"]
GraphicsColumn[{g1, ImageAdjust@ImageTake[soho, {175, 375}, {130, 400}]}]
```

[image]